# Convert 10 nodes to 3 nodes

Tags: ns2

This is a module of my project, the followin program is for 10 nodes, if i try converting it to 3 nodes i am not able to execute the program. any help is appreciated

```
enter code here
# Define options
set val(chan) Channel/WirelessChannel    ;# channel type
set val(prop) Propagation/TwoRayGround   ;# radio-propagation model

set val(netif)          Phy/WirelessPhy            ;# network interface type
set val(mac)            Mac/802_11                 ;# MAC type
set val(ifq)            Queue/DropTail/PriQueue    ;# interface queue type
set val(ll)             LL                         ;# link layer type
set val(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna        ;# antenna model
set val(ifqlen)         50                         ;# max packet in ifq
set val(nn)             10                      ;# number of mobilenodes
set val(rp)             DumbAgent                    ;# routing protocol
set val(x)              600                ;# X dimension of topography
set val(y)              600                ;# Y dimension of topography  



Mac/802_11 set dataRate_ 11Mb
# Global Variables
set ns_ [new Simulator]
set tracefd [open project1.tr w]
$ns_ trace-all $tracefd
set namtrace [open project1.nam w]
$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace $val(x) $val(y)
# set up topography object
set topo [new Topography]
$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)
# Create God
create-god $val(nn)
# Create channel
set chan_1_ [new $val(chan)]
$ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
    -llType $val(ll) \
    -macType $val(mac) \
    -ifqType $val(ifq) \
    -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
    -antType $val(ant) \
    -propType $val(prop) \
    -phyType $val(netif) \
    -topoInstance $topo \
    -agentTrace OFF \
    -routerTrace OFF \
    -macTrace ON \
    -movementTrace ON \
    -channel $chan_1_
for {set i 0} {$i < [expr $val(nn)]} {incr i} {
set node_($i) [$ns_ node]
$node_($i) random-motion 0;
set mac_($i) [$node_($i) getMac 0]
$mac_($i) set RTSThreshold_ 3000}
$node_(0) set X_ 200.0
$node_(0) set Y_ 360.0
$node_(0) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(1) set X_ 100.0
$node_(1) set Y_ 100.0
$node_(1) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(2) set X_ 400.0
$node_(2) set Y_ 400.0
$node_(2) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(3) set X_ 280.0
$node_(3) set Y_ 140.0
$node_(3) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(4) set X_ 100.0
$node_(4) set Y_ 320.0
$node_(4) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(5) set X_ 70.0
$node_(5) set Y_ 210.0
$node_(5) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(6) set X_ 440.0
$node_(6) set Y_ 310.0
$node_(6) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(7) set X_ 490.0
$node_(7) set Y_ 320.0
$node_(7) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(8) set X_ 520.0
$node_(8) set Y_ 280.0
$node_(8) set Z_ 0.0

$node_(9) set X_ 560.0
$node_(9) set Y_ 360.0
$node_(9) set Z_ 0.0
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(0) label AP1"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(1) label N1"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(2) label MN1"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(3) label MN2"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(4) label MN3"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(5) label MN4"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(6) label MN5"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(7) label MN6"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(8) label MN7"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(9) label AP2"

$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(0) add-mark m1 green circle"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(1) add-mark m1 red circle"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(2) add-mark m1 yellow circle"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(3) add-mark m1 blue circle"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(4) add-mark m1 purple circle"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(5) add-mark m1 pink circle"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(6) add-mark m1 red circle"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(7) add-mark m1 plum circle"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(8) add-mark m1 yellow circle"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(9) add-mark m1 grey circle"

set AP_ADDR1 [$mac_(0) id]
$mac_(0) ap $AP_ADDR1
set AP_ADDR2 [$mac_([expr $val(nn) - 1]) id]
$mac_([expr $val(nn) - 1]) ap $AP_ADDR2
$mac_(1) ScanType ACTIVE
for {set i 3} {$i < [expr $val(nn) - 1]} {incr i} {
    $mac_($i) ScanType PASSIVE      ;
}
$ns_ at 1.0 "$mac_(2) ScanType ACTIVE"
Application/Traffic/CBR set packetSize_ 1023
Application/Traffic/CBR set rate_ 256Kb

for {set i 1} {$i < [expr $val(nn) - 1]} {incr i} {
        set udp1($i) [new Agent/UDP]
        $ns_ attach-agent $node_($i) $udp1($i)
    set cbr1($i) [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
    $cbr1($i) attach-agent $udp1($i)
}


set null0 [new Agent/Null]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $null0
$ns_ connect $udp1(2) $null0

set null1 [new Agent/Null]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $null1
$ns_ connect $udp1(3) $null1

set null2 [new Agent/Null]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $null2
$ns_ connect $udp1(4) $null2

set null3 [new Agent/Null]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $null3
$ns_ connect $udp1(5) $null3

set null4 [new Agent/Null]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $null4
    $ns_ connect $udp1(6) $null4

set null5 [new Agent/Null]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $null5
$ns_ connect $udp1(7) $null5

set null6 [new Agent/Null]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(1) $null6
$ns_ connect $udp1(8) $null6

for {set i 0} {$i < [expr $val(nn)]} {incr i} {
$ns_ initial_node_pos $node_($i) 30
}


$ns_ at 8.0 "$cbr1(2) start"
$ns_ at 2.0 "$cbr1(3) start"
$ns_ at 3.0 "$cbr1(4) start"
$ns_ at 4.0 "$cbr1(5) start"
$ns_ at 5.0 "$cbr1(6) start"
$ns_ at 6.0 "$cbr1(7) start"
$ns_ at 7.0 "$cbr1(8) start"


$ns_ at 10.0 "$node_(4) setdest 590.0 350.0 1000.0"

$ns_ at 35.0 "$node_(5) setdest 460.0 360.0 1000.0"
$ns_ at 50.0 "$node_(3) setdest 590.0 350.0 1000.0"
$ns_ at 52.0 "$node_(3) setdest 100.0 360.0 1000.0"

$ns_ at 100.0 "stop"
$ns_ at 100.0 "puts \"NS EXITING...\" ; $ns_ halt"

proc stop {} {
global ns_ tracefd
$ns_ flush-trace
close $tracefd
exec nam project1.nam
exit 0
}
puts "Starting Simulation..."
$ns_ run
```

This is a module of my project, the followin program is for 10 nodes, if i try converting it to 3 nodes i am not able to execute the program. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reduce all relevant lines to use nodes { 0, 1, 2 } only,

and edit the remaining lines, until you have a usable result.

( I used 5 minutes, pure guess with some lines, but it works.)

Example, your edited file, "3-DSR.tcl"

Link at 'Google Docs' https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNRFFlaTRGaWt1V3M/view?usp=sharing

-

Comment: can u please xplain as to y u changed $udp1(2) to $udp1(1) and y did u uncomment  `# $ns_ connect $udp1(1) $null2`

Answer (score 0):

3-DSR.tcl :  Pure experimental // sketchy.
I just did some random changes, until :

1) I got a result, that worked with no errors.

2) And did one more change, to have all three nodes visible in 'nam'.

*** Actually I don't know how ns2 simulations are working, and why.

But : Long time experience (~5 years) building ns2-[all-versions], [all additional protocols], binary ns2 packages, patches, and thousands of simulations tests : I sometimes have the luck getting new things to work.